# C# add text to text file without rewriting it?

Tags: c#, file, filestream, streamwriter

Let's say I have the following code:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(Path));
sw.Write("Some stuff here");
sw.Dispose();
```

This code replaces the contents of the file with "Some stuff here," however I would like to **add** text to the file rather than replacing the text. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the `StreamWriter` you want to append:

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```

[`File.OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx) doesn't support appending.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) method and replace the 3 lines of code you have with:

```
File.AppendAllText(Path, "blah");
```

This way you don't have to worry about streams and disposing them (even in the event of an exception which by the way you are not doing properly) and the code is pretty simple and straightforward to the point.

Answer (score 4):

Check out System.IO.File.AppendAllText

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx

You can do what you want doing something like

```
File.AppendAllText(path, text);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a StreamWriter constructor which takes a bool as the 2nd parameter, which instructs the writer to append if true.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `append` parameter:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path, true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To append text to a file, you can open it using `FileMode.Append`.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path, System.IO.FileMode.Append));
```

This is just one way to do it. Although, if you don't explicitly need the `StreamWriter` object, I would recommend using what others have suggested: `File.AppendAllText`.